# Back button disabling links in content placeholder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, back-button, linkbutton

I have *links in a content panel* which will fire when page is new/refreshed. But if you navigate throughout the page then **hit the back button** to go back to the main page, *none of the linkbutton events in the content panel fire.*

I am just kind of loss - what would cause this functionality. I can post code if needed but I really am just looking for suggestions as to where to start looking.

Comment: How are you firing those links? Is there some js that calls a click? Showing that code would help.

Comment: Please show us some code so we might be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the [asp page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) - to make sense of why the event you are expecting to fire hasn't.